# Weird behavior of variadic macro expansion with gcc and clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, variadic-macros

I'm writing a variadic dispatcher macro in C++, to call a different macro based on the number of arguments (from none up to 5) provided to the dispatcher. I came up with this solution:

```
#define GETOVERRIDE(_ignored, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, NAME, ...) NAME
#define NAMEDARGS(...) GETOVERRIDE(ignored, ##__VA_ARGS__, NAMEDARGS5, NAMEDARGS4, NAMEDARGS3, NAMEDARGS2, NAMEDARGS1, NAMEDARGS0)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

NAMEDARGS is the dispatcher macro; calling it with 1 argument will result in a call to NAMEDARGS1 which takes 1 argument, and so on (I don't provide the implementations of the various NAMEDARGS# since they are irrelevant in this context).

I tested the code gcc 7.1.1, and I found a weird behavior of the gcc expansion when using the -std=c++14 flag. With this test code:

```
NAMEDARGS()
NAMEDARGS(int)
NAMEDARGS(int, float)
```

I get these expansions:

```
$ gcc -E testMacro.cpp
NAMEDARGS0()
NAMEDARGS1(int)
NAMEDARGS2(int, float)

$ gcc -E -std=c++14 testMacro.cpp
NAMEDARGS1()
NAMEDARGS1(int)
NAMEDARGS2(int, float)
```

It seems that using the -std=c++14 flag the substitution of the zero-argument call fails, resulting in the call of the one-argument macro. I thought that this could be because the ##__VA_ARGS__ syntax is a GNU extension, thus not working with an ISO C++ preprocessor; however, when trying with clang 4.0.1 I obtain the desired expansion:

```
$ clang -E -std=c++14 testMacro.cpp
NAMEDARGS0()
NAMEDARGS1(int)
NAMEDARGS2(int, float)
```

So I don't understand what's going on here. Does clang implement this gnu extension, accepting non-ISO code also with -std==c++14 unlike gcc? Or maybe the problem lies elsewhere? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

GCC defaults `-std` to `gnu++14` (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html)), which is C++14 with GNU extensions.

Comparing the two with only `NAMEDARGS(...)` defined shows how the expansions differ:

**Code**

```
#define NAMEDARGS(...) GETOVERRIDE(ignored, ##__VA_ARGS__, NAMEDARGS5, NAMEDARGS4, NAMEDARGS3, NAMEDARGS2, NAMEDARGS1, NAMEDARGS0)(__VA_ARGS__)
NAMEDARGS()
```

**-std=gnu++14 -E**

```
GETOVERRIDE(ignored, NAMEDARGS5, NAMEDARGS4, NAMEDARGS3, NAMEDARGS2, NAMEDARGS1, NAMEDARGS0)()
-------------------^
```

**-std=c++14 -E**

```
GETOVERRIDE(ignored,, NAMEDARGS5, NAMEDARGS4, NAMEDARGS3, NAMEDARGS2, NAMEDARGS1, NAMEDARGS0)()
-------------------^^
```

I'm not an experienced standard reader, but I found the following two passages in **[cpp.replace]** which suggest that GCC is correct in both invocations:

> If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis, the number of arguments (including those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens) in an invocation of a function-like macro shall equal the number of parameters in the macro definition. **Otherwise, there shall be more arguments in the invocation than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the ...).** There shall exist a ) preprocessing token that terminates the invocation.

...

> If there is a ... immediately preceding the ) in the function-like macro definition, then the trailing arguments, including any separating comma preprocessing tokens, are merged to form a single item: the variable arguments. **The number of arguments so combined is such that, following merger, the number of arguments is one more than the number of parameters in the macro definition (excluding the ...).**

It seems correct then that an empty `__VA_ARGS__` is expanded to a single empty argument.

I can't find whether clang's behaviour here is intended.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this is exactly what I thought, and the reason why I decided to try with a (supposed) ISO C++ preprocessor like clang (at least AFAIK). I expected a similar behavior to gcc -std=c++14 and got surprised when seeing the result.